# batch: check existence of a file with "()" in its path

Tags: batch-file, scripting

In batch scripts I can check for existens of a file like this:

```
if exist "C:\myfile.txt" (
    :: do some action here
)
```

I can also check for files which are stored in variable names:

```
set MY_FILE="C:\myfile.txt"
if exist "%MY_FILE%" (
    :: do some action here
)
```

Unfortunately, if the filename contains brackets `()` this does not work:

```
set MY_FILE="C:\Program Files (x86)\myfile.txt"
if exist "%MY_FILE%" (
    :: do some action here
)
```

Batch somehow interprets the brackets within the filepath as the block of the if statement.

How can I check for existence of a file with `()` in it's path?

Comment: try with `set "MY_FILE=C:\Program Files (x86)\myfile.txt"`

Comment: You are putting quotes around the file name in your `SET` command _and_ in your `IF` statement. You only need to quote it in one place.

Comment: Seems like the first thing I would have tried would have been: `IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\" ECHO EXISTS`.  Which works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, batch scripting sometimes is just confusing. I figured it out somehow.

First I removed the quotes from the `SET` commands as the filepath is assembled through several calls to `SET`. Thanks for pointing this out.

Second the error turned out to be within the `()` brackets of the `IF` statement. I echoed the value of the filename somewhere using

```
echo MY_FILE:%MY_FILE%
```

This caused the brackets within the pathname to be interpreted badly within the if-block. I am not perfectly sure but I believe this can be connected to having  `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` enabled in the beginning of my script.

After changing the above echo line to

```
echo MY_FILE:!MY_FILE!
```

everything works now.